# The Chinese remainder theorem for modules.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Let $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$. Then 
$${M}/{a_1a_2M}\cong {a_1M}/{a_1a_2M} \oplus {a_2M}/{a_1a_2M}.$$

> Is the above statement true? If not, what kind of restrictions we need to consider to make it true?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me write $a=a_1$ and $b=a_2$, for simplicity and let's assume $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$. There is an obvious homomorphism
$$
f\colon\frac{aM}{abM}\oplus\frac{bM}{abM}\to\frac{M}{abM}
$$
defined by
$$
f(ax+abM,by+abM)=ax+by+abM
$$
Let $z\in M$; can we find $x,y\in M$ such that $f(ax+abM,by+abM)=z+abM$? Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we can write $1=ah+bk$, so $z=ahz+bkz$.

What's the kernel of $f$?
$$
f(ax+abM,by+abM)=0+abM
$$
if and only if $ax+by\in abM$, that is $ax+by=abz$ for some $z\in M$, which implies
$$
by=a(x-bz)
$$
Write $x=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_iv_i$, $y=\sum_{i\in I}\beta_iv_i$ and $z=\sum_{i\in I}\gamma_iv_i$, where $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $M$. Then
$$
b\beta_i=a(\alpha_i-b\gamma_i)\qquad(i\in I).
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the last line was not clear to me. You say that it is a surjective homomorphism?  ${M}/{a_1a_2M}\cong {a_1M}/{a_1a_2M} \oplus {a_2M}/{a_1a_2M}\oplus {a_1a_2M}$? Best regards

Comment: @user31009 Yes, it is surjective: $f(ahz+abM,bkz+abM)=ahz+bkz+abM=z+abM$. The last line refers to showing it is injective.

Comment: @ egreg  Can you please correct me if I was wrong: Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $a\mid \beta_i$. Thus $y=ag$ with $g \in M$,and then $by=abg\in abM$. Similar $ax\in abM$. Best regards.

Comment: @user31009 Correct.

Comment: Sorry for bumping, but couldn't you take the canonical morphism $M\to (aM)/(abM)\oplus (bM)/(abM)$, and see that it's onto with kernel $abM$?

Comment: @JoBe Yes, that's possible.